# What is the actual format of filedescriptor that is used in mediamuxer?

Tags: java, android, file

I want to save my mediaMuxer data in memory so I used ParcelFileDescriptor to save data in memory but given IllegalStateException and mediaMuxer did not start. I have tried several techniques like MemoryFile, Socket, ByteOutputStream but got the same exception. Bellow is my sample code

```
try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
            outputParcelFileDescriptor = pipe[1];
            FileDescriptor fd = outputParcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();

            String text = "MemoryFile Text";

   

            MediaMuxer mediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(fd, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

            MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC, 640, 480);

            // Configure media format
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 2000000);
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
            mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);

            // Create the encoder and input surface
            MediaCodec mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);
            mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            Surface inputSurface = mediaCodec.createInputSurface();
            mediaCodec.start();

            // Render text frames onto the input surface
            Canvas canvas = inputSurface.lockCanvas(null);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setTextSize(40);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawText(text, 100, 240, paint);
            inputSurface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

            // Encode and mux frames
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
            boolean muxing = true;

            while (muxing) {
                int encoderStatus = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, -1);
                if (encoderStatus >= 0) {
                    ByteBuffer encodedData = outputBuffers[encoderStatus];

                    if ((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
                        bufferInfo.size = 0;
                    }

                    if (bufferInfo.size != 0) {
                        encodedData.position(bufferInfo.offset);
                        encodedData.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);
                        mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(0, encodedData, bufferInfo);
                    }

                    mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);

                    if ((bufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                    // Configure the media format for the muxer
                    MediaFormat outputFormat = mediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
                    mediaMuxer.addTrack(outputFormat);
                    mediaMuxer.start();
                }
            }

            mediaMuxer.stop();
            mediaMuxer.release();
            mediaCodec.stop();
            mediaCodec.release();
            outputParcelFileDescriptor.close();
           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.toString());

        }
```

I have tried several methods to save data in memory but got the same IllegalStateException